# How to solve Integration of Linkedin in android

Tags: android, social-networking, linkedin-api

I am trying to integrate Linkedin in my project from so many days right now m using this Link for integration  https://github.com/srivastavavivek1987/LinkedIn-Connection-in-Android
but it throws such error in logcat

06-03 17:02:35.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 17:02:35.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29795): Process: com.example.linkedin,                    PID: 29795
06-03 17:02:35.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29795):com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=w_share+r_basicprofile

I search many replies and tried them but cant get satisfy result can somebody help me to resolve this 
or can someone give me running code for Linkedin integration with android

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue it is just server problem with that of if your callback URI is not same at developers console in authentication at OAuth 2.0 and OAuth 1.0, and in program then such type of problem creates just make it absolute path at everywhere with correct client id and client secret
Use this link it helps a lot
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#authorize